# How can we use same partition schema with different partition function?

Tags: sql, partitioning

I'm learning table partitioning.
When I read [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191174.aspx), it said that

> The `TransactionHistoryArchive` table must have the **same design schema** as the `TransactionHistory` table. There must also be an empty partition to receive the new data. In this case, `TransactionHistoryArchive` is a partitioned table that consists of just two partitions.

And with the following picture, we can see that `TransactionHistory` has 12 partitions, but `TransactionHistoryArchive` just has 2 partitions.

[Illustration http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC38652.gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC38652.gif)

How could it possible? Please help me to understand it.

Comment: The picture seems to be missing.

Comment: the picture I meant that is in the msdn link, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as two individual partitions have identical schema and the same boundary values you can switch them. They don't need to have the same partition scheme or function.

This is because SQL Server ensures that the binary data of those partitions on disk is compatible. That's the magic of partitioning and why you can move arbitrary amounts of data as a quick metadata-only operation.